# Silverlight databinding crm types

Tags: silverlight, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, model-binding

I am retrieving money type objects from an entity in crm which I display on a grid, 
I would like to display this as a string however so I can see the value.

How would I do this in silverlight, do I need a convertor?

Comment: What is it displaying as at the moment? Do you mean you just want it formatted nicer? Money comes through as the `decimal` type, so a converter (with optional formatting parameter for extreme niceness) would be suitable.

Comment: solved it, its the money attribute type then .Value to do the conversion